# S3 bucket policy via a particular application

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3-bucket

I am trying to utilize S3 to let my clients download my software package. What I envision is creating a simple web app with authorization For example (`download.mysoftware.com`) Once the user is authenticated, they will be presented with a S3 url used to download the software. I will create user accounts based on my customers.

My concern is, what happens if the user copies the S3 URL link and then gives it to someone who isn't authenticated to download the software?

Is it possible to create an S3 policy that would prevent this and work for my usecase? I looked at allowing only specific IPs, however, I won't have a way to find out IP of my customers and wouldn't want to ask them first and then add it to the policy each time.

One way allowing specific IPs would work is if I allow downloads only from the IP that is linked to (`download.mysoftware.com`) but then the downloads will really be happened from my web application as opposed to from S3. Which seems like double effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user makes a request to download your application, generate a [pre-signed URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) for them with a short expiration. It only needs to be valid for as long as it takes them to *start* downloading your file, so even a few minutes of validity is likely to be plenty.

While it's technically possible for a user to share one of these URLs, they would have to convey the URL to someone else and get them to download it very quickly, which is probably sufficient to deter them from trying to share the URL. (A perfect defense is more difficult, and is probably unnecessary anyways; there's no way to prevent a user from personally transferring a file they downloaded to someone else.)